# Issue to access data on json response from https request from nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I have coded an HTTPS function using the native https module from NodeJS to get some JSON from an API.

When I'm doing a GET request I'm getting the JSON fine, but when I have to make a PUT request I got the JSON but I can't convert that into an object.

answer from GET:

```
{
  items: [
    { dsname: 'A09999' },
    { dsname: 'A09999.ALLFILES.TEMP' },
  ],
  returnedRows: 16,
  JSONversion: 1
}
```

answer from PUT:

```
{
  'cmd-response-key': 'C8124546',
  'cmd-response-url':'https://myhost/zosmf/restconsoles/consoles/ibmusecn/solmsgs/C8124546',
  'cmd-response-uri': '/zosmf/restconsoles/consoles/ibmusecn/solmsgs/C8124546',
  'cmd-response':
   ' IEE457I 16.32.55 UNIT STATUS 464\r UNIT TYPE STATUS        VOLSER' }
```

My code:

```
const makeRequest = options =>
    new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        let results = https.request(options, res => {
            res.setEncoding('utf8');
            let body = '';

            res.on('data', data => {
                body += data;
            });
            res.on('end', () => {
                body = JSON.parse(body);
                console.log('body :', body);
                resolve(body);
            });
        });
        if (options.body) {
            // results.write(options.body);
            results.write(JSON.stringify(options.body),['Transfer-Encoding', 'chunked']);
        }
        results.on('error', e => {
            reject(e);
        });
        results.end();
    });
```

Comment: Neither of these is valid JSON. But maybe you are showing the already parsed JSON? Can't tell.

Answer (score 1):

Well what you are getting back from the post is not a valid json object. This bit right here:

```
'cmd-response':
   ' IEE457I 16.32.55 UNIT STATUS 464\r UNIT TYPE STATUS        VOLSER'' }
```

Notice how at the end, VOLSER is followed by to ''. This ends the string starting the value and opens a new string. This is invalid JSON.

Also, I'd recommend using a library like axios or request from npm. Well written, widely used, and not as low level as using the https module directly.

Comment: That second ' was pasted by mistake, i'm not getting it on the answer, anyway it's not comeing as expected :(

Comment: By the way i just tried with AXIOS and i'm getting the answer in same format... i will report it for who is responsible for maintain that api, since i can just think it may be a problem in the side of the api that is not proper handling the answer